# HTTP POSTed files automatically uploaded to root directory

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, webforms

I just inherited an ASP.NET WebForms web application that I was tasked with refactoring.

One of the features is a file upload and while debugging I noticed that as soon as a file is posted to a certain page/handler, it is automatically uploaded to the root directory of the application. The file is then moved to the proper location.

I can't seem to figure out whats causing this automatic upload of the file. Is there something I'am overlooking in ASP.NET WebForms that allows this to happen? Is it an IIS configuration or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there was an HTTP module that would save any posted files to the root directory. All I need to do was remove it from the `web.config` file.